# How should we treat people who announce attempts of illegal behavior?

Tags: discussion

[Very similar to this question](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1405/how-should-questions-answers-on-how-to-do-something-illegal-be-treated), but in this case the problem is that someone threatens to attempt something illegal.

The trigger for the question is this comment under the question: [inland removal after detention](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/121563/inland-removal-after-detention?noredirect=1&lq=1)

> Musonius Rufus: Going pay a lawyer is not a matter of your concern ok? If you are not ken to answer just don't! No one is forcing you! With regard to your opinion just keep it for you. **I shall return to UK, will you like it or not!** And try to be a bit polite I am not your servant ok!!!!!!!!!!

Now in this case I do not take it seriously. The person seems to be quite hot-headed, very frustated and angry and in this case you say dumb things you later regret.

**But it got me thinking: What if we see how someone convincingly ask a question or give an answer which indicates that an illegal attempt is in progress? Without extenuating circumstances which would allow us to simply help someone? (There was this forced marriage question which caused quite a stir).**

ADDITION: It is not the same as the cited question. The cited question is the situation if someone asks e.g. "How can I circumvent the border controls of country XYZ to enter the country illegally?". This problem is if someone asks "**I am now near the border of country XYZ at location ABC and will try to go over it**. What is the best location for the attempt?".

The situation is different now, it is not only discussing a hypothetical situation, it is that someonce communicates clearly the intent to breach the law now or in short time.

I do not feel comfortable in my skin at all. Should we ignore it because we cannot prove intent, raising wrong alarms or giving malicious trolls something to feed or should we (everyone? moderators?) inform the SE team or other authorities? How do you feel about it?

Comment: Thinking over it: Should we move the question to meta because it concerns practically all topics?

Comment: This was discussed long ago: https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1405/how-should-questions-answers-on-how-to-do-something-illegal-be-treated

Comment: @NeanDerThal I must disagree. The discussion was over giving information about an attempted illegal activity, I am talking about the situation that the illegal activity is currently in progress oder to be expected soon.

Comment: ok, that's a fair point.

Answer (score 5):

I think there is no one rule here. Each case should be treated spearately using the current site tools (downvotes, flags, comments, edits), the community should be able to decide.

If we make a general rule, someone will always jump the gun and takes the wrong decision thinking that the post fits the pre-defined criteria, IMHO.